# SQL Server which query runs faster

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
UPDATE User 
SET Name = (SELECT NameSpace.NameId 
            FROM NameSpace 
            WHERE NameSpace.Name = 'BlaBlaBla') 
WHERE UserId = 1453
```

This is faster or

```
int Value = Select NameSpace.NameId from NameSpace 
            where NameSpace.Name = 'BlaBlaBla';

UPDATE User 
SET Name = "+Value +" 
WHERE UserId = 1453
```

and

```
Select 
    UserName,
    UserAge,
    (Select * from AdressesTable where Adresses.AdresID=User.AdresID) 
from 
    UserTable
where
    UserId='123'
```

OR

```
Select * 
from AdressesTable, UserTable 
where Adresses.AdresID = User.AdresID AND UserID = '123'
```

Comment: One query is faster than 2 seperate queries. And normally a join is better than a subquery.

Comment: Why don't you time them?

Comment: @Shadow I am going to time them but i dont have most of value in table. I couldn't see anything . I dont have any data for try it.

Comment: *If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster then **race your horses*** - see [Which is faster?](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) by Eric Lippert for more background

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @juergend So first one is faster than Right ?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of assumptions to be made in determining which is faster.

First, if you are concerned about speed, then you want indexes on `users(userid)` and `namespace(name)`.

Second, the assignment query should look like this in SQL Server:

```
declare @Value int;

select @Value = NameSpace.NameId
from NameSpace 
where NameSpace.Name = 'BlaBlaBla';
```

Your variable declarations and subqueries are not correct for SQL Server.

Finally, even with everything set up correctly, it is not possible to say which is faster.  If I assume that there is only one matching record for `UserId`, then the single `update` is probably faster -- although perhaps by so little that it is not noticeable.  It may not be faster.  The update may cause some sort of lock to be taken on `NameSpace` that would not otherwise be taken.  I would actually expect the two to be quite comparable in speed.

However, if many users have the same `userid` (which is unlikely given the name of the column), then you are doing updates on multiple rows.  Storing the calculated result once and using that is probably better than running the subquery multiple times.  Even so, with the right indexes, I would expect the difference in performance to be negligible.

Comment: Hmm I think JOİN is faster than all of this. If i use the Join , SQL server answer me faster. right ?

Comment: @MuhammedAlmaz . . . I don't think you read the answer.  You need proper indexes for better performance; and in some cases a variable might be marginally faster.